# iOS charts v3.5 chartViewDidEndPanning not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I have this `LineChartView`

```
let Chart = LineChartView()
Chart.delegate = self   // self adopts ChartViewDelegate
Chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
Chart.legend.enabled = false
Chart.xAxis.enabled = false
Chart.noDataText = ""
```

the problem is that whenever I finish panning through the chart the `func chartViewDidEndPanning(_ chartView: ChartViewBase)` is not getting called even though I implement the `ChartViewDelegate` protocol and the `func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)` is getting properly called when ever I start panning. Anyone else got this issue?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: For my needs using a timer In `chartValueSelected`  to deselect the value and do some cleanup works good enough.

Comment: Exactly the question need with no answer! 